# show additional rows based on field value (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which shows the result as follows

```
NAME   RATIO
====   =====
S        3
M        2
```

I want to make Ratio Groups (A,B,C .....) based on Names For Example, there are 3 ratios for Name S so A,B,C Group will be made for S and D,E will be made for M. The result I want to be displayed will be like this

```
NAME      GROUP
====      =====
S           A
S           B
S           C
M           D
M           E
```

To pass Letter dynamically, I tried using the the ANSI Characater CHR(65) for A and so on.. but couldn't find a way to write the query.

How can I achieve this using SQL Query?

Regards

Comment: You have the S groups alphabetically before the M groups - is there something that determines that, like another column in your table/result you haven't shown, or reverse-alphabetic for the name value, or something else? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: What is the logic of labeling the groups with upper-case letters (A, B, C, ...) and not integers (1, 2, 3, ...)? It seems more natural that they should be integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive subquery factoring to generate the extra rows:

```
with rcte (name, ratio, lvl) as (
  select name, ratio, 1
  from your_table
  union all
  select name, ratio, lvl + 1
  from rcte
  where lvl < ratio
)
select name, ratio
from rcte
-- order by 'name desc' to get same order shown in question
order by name desc, ratio;

NAME RATIO
---- -----
S        3
S        3
S        3
M        2
M        2
```

And then get the row number for each of those, and add that to `chr(64)` to get the corresponding letter. As long as you don't have too many groups, of course...

```
with rcte (name, ratio, lvl) as (
  select name, ratio, 1
  from your_table
  union all
  select name, ratio, lvl + 1
  from rcte
  where lvl < ratio
)
select name, ratio,
  -- order by 'name desc' to get same order shown in question
  chr(64 + row_number() over (order by name desc, ratio, lvl)) as grp
from rcte
order by grp

NAME RATIO GRP
---- ----- ---
S        3 A
S        3 B
S        3 C
M        2 D
M        2 E
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d9ff283f6e3b0651554689691f966625)

It isn't obvious why the 'S' rows come before and have groups starting first, before the 'M' ones. Do get your expected result I've just based the ordering on the reverse-alphabetic sort of the name values - if you have something more sensible (like another column you haven't shown) then change the `order by` clause to use that instead.